# Meteor.js and npm

Tags: javascript, node.js, meteor

So I'm using the Meteor package [meteorhacks:npm](https://github.com/meteorhacks/npm) in order to use npm packages from within my meteor code. So I have a template:

```
Template.upload.events({
    'submit form': function(event){
        var file1 = document.getElementById("file1").files;

        var file2 = $('[name=file1]').val();
        //console.log(file1[0].type);

        var reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onload = function(event) {
            var contents = event.target.result;
            Meteor.call("saveFileinFolder",contents);
            //console.log(contents);

        };
```

And this is the Meteor method that I'm calling:

```
Meteor.methods({
    saveFileinFolder: function (content){
        var nodeFS = Meteor.npmRequire('node-fs');
        var fs = new nodeFS({version:'0.1.7'});
        console.log(content);
    }
});
```

I'm trying to use the node package node-fs in order to save a file to a folder, but I keep getting the error :

```
I20150825-18:37:51.645(-4)? Exception while invoking method 'saveFileinFolder' TypeError: object is not a function
I20150825-18:37:51.646(-4)?     at [object Object].Meteor.methods.saveFileinFolder (app/server/home.js:4:15)
I20150825-18:37:51.646(-4)?     at maybeAuditArgumentChecks (packages/ddp/livedata_server.js:1617:1)
I20150825-18:37:51.646(-4)?     at packages/ddp/livedata_server.js:648:1
I20150825-18:37:51.646(-4)?     at [object Object]._.extend.withValue (packages/meteor/dynamics_nodejs.js:56:1)
I20150825-18:37:51.646(-4)?     at packages/ddp/livedata_server.js:647:1
I20150825-18:37:51.646(-4)?     at [object Object]._.extend.withValue (packages/meteor/dynamics_nodejs.js:56:1)
I20150825-18:37:51.646(-4)?     at [object Object]._.extend.protocol_handlers.method (packages/ddp/livedata_server.js:646:1)
I20150825-18:37:51.646(-4)?     at packages/ddp/livedata_server.js:546:1
```

Answer (score 0):

You are misunderstanding the way to use meteorhacks:npm. You need to put the version number you want into a file called `packages.json`:

{ "node-fs": "0.1.7" }

then restart meteor and it will install that node package for you. Then in your code, proceed as with a usual `require`, just use `Meteor.npmRequire` instead. You will get the same object as from `require` in node.

Comment: I have a packages.json file with node-fs specified in it. Also, Meteor.require is deprecated . I did try everything you suggested and still no luck

Comment: could you update your question with the `new nodeFS({version:'0.1.7'});` bug resolved? That line will definitely throw an error.